# How to get native php http 500 error pages in symfony2?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, error-handling

In Symfony2 I'm getting a custom twig error message when an error 500 is thrown:

*Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.*

I just want default php errors instead.
If possible, only in dev.

**display_errors** is **on** in php.ini and looking at phpinfo()

I tried to add the following lines to app/config/config.yml

```
services:  
    twig.exception_listener:
        class: DateTime
        #dummy to prevent twig from handling http error pages
```

The result is that I get a blank page instead of the php error page with error and lines for debugging.

Thanks,
Boris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Symfony2 wraps the whole process from the Request to the Response. Native PHP errors occur when not caught by Symfony2.
And native PHP errors can't be thrown if it's not a native PHP error. You'd get a real 500 error code page only if Symfony2 core would fail in rendering the response.

I don't see any other explanations. You can find more information about the error process by flowing [this link](http://www.webfactory.de/blog/symfony2-exception-handling-and-custom-error-pages-explained).

This links explains why you do have a blank page : 500 error code exception is thrown but Twig is not listening this event anymore (as you disabled it). So nothing happens.

Comment: But is it possible to handle and render the error output e.g. though twig? I would love to see the cause for the error instead of a standard message. And opening the log section each time consumes a lot of time. How do you debug instead?

Comment: When in dev mode, Twig prints the Exception and the error content by default. You may have changed this setting ?

Comment: Not me, but then it obviously has been changed. :) I'll have a look. Thanks.